# Python DRF PrimaryKeyRelatedField to use uuid instead of PK

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a Django REST Framework API.
My models have default Django PK for internal use AND uuid field for external reference.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Event(BaseModel):
    title = models.TextField()
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Location(BaseModel):
    latitude  = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

And my serializers:

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    default_fields = ('uuid',)                                                                        

class EventSerializer(BaseSerializer):                                                                                                                   
    class Meta:                                                                  
        model = Event                                                                                 
        lookup_field = 'uuid' # This does not work                                                                      
        fields = BaseSerializer.default_fields + ('title', 'location',)

class LocationSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        lookup_field = 'uuid' # This does not work 
        fields = BaseSerializer.default_fields + ('latitude', 'longitude',)
```

This works fine, here is what I got when I retrieve an Event:

```
{
    "uuid": "ef33db27-e98b-4c26-8817-9784dfd546c6",
    "title": "UCI Worldcup #1 Salzburg",
    "location": 1 # Note here I have the PK, not UUID
}
```

But what I would like is:

```
{
    "uuid": "ef33db27-e98b-4c26-8817-9784dfd546c6",
    "title": "UCI Worldcup #1 Salzburg",
    "location": "2454abe7-7cde-4bcb-bf6d-aaff91c107bf" # I want UUID here
}
```

And of course I want this behavior to work for all my ForeignKeys and ManyToMany fields.
Is there a way to customize the field used by DRF for nested models ?
Thanks !

Comment: For classes that you need to get the number as a value rather than a UUID, dont extend them from the Basemodel. Django will by default create a ID field which will autoincrement when a new row is created. That

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from rest_framework.relations import RelatedField
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text


class UUIDRelatedField(RelatedField):
    """
    A read-write field that represents the target of the relationship
    by a unique 'slug' attribute.
    """
    default_error_messages = {
        'does_not_exist': _('Object with {uuid_field}={value} does not exist.'),
        'invalid': _('Invalid value.'),
    }

    def __init__(self, uuid_field=None, **kwargs):
        assert uuid_field is not None, 'The `uuid_field` argument is required.'
        self.uuid_field = uuid_field
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get(**{self.uuid_field: data})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', uuid_field=self.uuid_field, value=smart_text(data))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, self.uuid_field)
```

Sample Usage:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = UUIDRelatedField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        uuid_field='alias'
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'alias',
            'name',
            'category',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'id',
            'alias',
        )
```

Note that as of Django version 4, `smart_text` and `ugettext_lazy` were removed, use `smart_str` and `gettext_lazy` instead of them:

```
from django.utils.encoding import gettext_lazy
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
```

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine send me this solution:
It works with all my related objects.

```
from rest_framework import serializers                                                                
from rest_framework.relations import SlugRelatedField                 

class UuidRelatedField(SlugRelatedField):                                                             
    def __init__(self, slug_field=None, **kwargs):                                                    
        slug_field = 'uuid'
        super().__init__(slug_field, **kwargs)                                                        


class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                    
    default_fields = ('uuid',)                                                                        
    serializer_related_field = UuidRelatedField

    class Meta:                                                                                       
        pass
```

Comment: You  don't need to derive a new class, you can just use SlugRelatedField(slug_field='uuid') etc. in the serializer

Comment: Great, workable approach. Thank you!

@BjornW The idea is that one uses the BaseSerializer class instead of ModelSerializer. I think for that the approach above is best.

Answer (score 1):

For nested model fields you can use the `source` argument in a serializer like this

```
class EventSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    location = serializers.CharField(source='location.uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        lookup_field = 'uuid'  # This does not work
        fields = BaseSerializer.default_fields + ('title', 'location',)
```